# How to understand "main function's prototype cannot be supplied by the program"?

Tags: c

I read [main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function), and came across following words:

> The main function has several special properties:
>
> 1. A prototype for this function cannot be supplied by the program.

Then I wrote a simple program:

```
# cat foo.c
int main(void);

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it:

```
# gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror foo.c
#
```

All seems OK! So I am little confused about how to understand "A prototype for this function cannot be supplied by the program". Anyone can give some insights?

Comment: The C standard doesn't have that specification. It says that the implementation doesn't provide a prototype for `main()`, it doesn't say that the program itself can't have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard (5.1.2.2.1) just says that the compiler (for hosted systems like PC etc) will not provide a prototype for the `main` function. So cppreference.com isn't really correct, the C standard doesn't prohibit the application programmer from writing a prototype, although doing so is probably meaningless practice in hosted systems.

In freestanding systems (embedded systems etc), it might be meaningful to declare a prototype for `main` in case it needs to be called from a reset ISR or from the "C runtime" (CRT).

What's important to realize no matter system is that the *compiler* specifies which forms of `main` that are valid. Never the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

`main` function parameters and the return value is defined by the standard. You shall not provide your own one. But the compiler may accept and compile even non standard types of `main`.

On the other hand, the `main` function will not be called by **your** code so your prototype is not needed at all.

Comment: C allows the main function to be called by other user-supplied code

Comment: "But the compiler will accept and compile even non standard types of main" Well, maybe? The compiler is free to support implementation-defined formats, which it must the document. And then the programmer might use those provided formats. The compiler doesn't need to support some crazy programmer inventing their own formats of `main` - such formats of `main` not explicitly documented/supported by  the compiler are undefined behavior.